# Application error: a client-side exception has occurred(IN NEXT,JS 13)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

## **Introduction:**

I'm currently working on a Weather Application. I build this Application with the help of **Next.js 13** after completing the project i build the project with the help of **yarn run build** in my local machine it is working fine but when i deploy this project on vercel it's home page is working but my dynamic routes are not working

**gitHub :** [code Link](https://github.com/1741Rishabh/weather-Appication)

## **local system Outcome:**

### Front page

[image]

### dynamic page

[image]

## vercel Outcome

### Front page vercel

[image]

### dynamic page in vercel (error)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to be sure what gone wrong without the logs from Vercel, but at the very least - your `getCityId` uses `localhost` to get data:

```
const getcityid = async (id) => {
    const city = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/citibyid?id=${id}`)
    const citydata = await city.json();
    return citydata
}
```

You need to use relative path, like:

```
const city = await fetch(`/api/citibyid?id=${id}`)
```

Also make sure that environment variable `API_KEY` for openweathermap is set on Vercel.

Comment: Thank you help but this  (const city = await fetch(`/api/citibyid?id=${id}`))  is also showing error in server so i change the URL in      (https://weather-appication.vercel.app/api/citibyid?id=${id}`) and this solve the error so if anyone get the same error simply change the domain name while fetching on server. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

...Try full dynamic page with adding `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';` to the `..location/[city] /page.js`  ( and basically remove    `next: {revalidate: 10000}` from fetches) -- maybe issues're caused by inconsistencies btw server-prerendered (which should  be the default city?) and dynamically rendered on the fly [city] pages ...
(also, why not to set `title=`${cityreport.city.name} Weather - Next Weather App`to`metadata` object itself (as by docs) ...